# Find cubic bezier from easing function

Tags: javascript, css-animations, css-transitions, cubic-bezier

I have a function returning an easing function that takes 3 parameters and return the css propertyValue at percentComplete time: `function(percentComplete, startValue, endValue)`.

But to be useful to me, I need its cubic-bezier `cubicBezier(<P1x>,<P1y>,<P2x>,<P2y>)`, how can I achieve that ?